# How does pattern matching work with ref in Rust?

Tags: rust, cockroachdb

Just came across this code from [here](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/build-a-rust-app-with-cockroachdb.html#insecure):

```
...
    let mut txn = client.transaction()?;
    loop {
        let mut sp = txn.savepoint("cockroach_restart")?;
        match op(&mut sp).and_then(|t| sp.commit().map(|_| t)) {
            Err(ref err)
                if err
                    .code()
                    .map(|e| *e == SqlState::T_R_SERIALIZATION_FAILURE)
                    .unwrap_or(false) => {}
            r => break r,
        }
    }
    .and_then(|t| txn.commit().map(|_| t))
...
```

It's not very clear what's happening inside the `match` block.

1. Why is there no handling for `Ok` variant after handling `Err`?
2. Where does `r` come from?
3. What's the logic with `err.code()...`? It's mapping from pointer to bool but then unwrap on a bool??? and then do nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is there no handling for `Ok` variant after handling `Err`?

The second arm of the match is a catch-all pattern that matches any value, so it covers the `Ok` variant, as well as the `Err` variant for which the guard in the first variant fails.

> Where does `r` come from?

When an identifier like `r` is used as the pattern, it represents a new local variable that captures the matched value.

> What's the logic with `err.code()`...?

`postgres::Error::code()` returns an `Option<&SqlState>`. If the code is provided (the option is `Some`), and equal to `SqlState::T_R_SERIALIZATION_FAILURE`, the loop continues. If it is other than `T_R_SERIALIZATION_FAILURE` or not provided (the option is `None`), the match guard returns false and the catch-all pattern is executed instead, stopping the loop.

To unravel handling of `code()` step by step:

- `postgres::Error::code()` returns `Option<&SqlState>`.
- `Option<&SqlState>::map(closure)` maps `Option<&SqlState>` to `Option<type returned by the closure>`. The closure is called only if the option is `Some`, otherwise `Option::map` just returns `None`. Since our closure just evaluates a `==`, it returns `bool` and `map` therefore returns `Option<bool>`. (The closure must use `*` to dereference the value because it receives `&SqlState`.)
- `Option<bool>::unwrap_or(default_value)` evaluates to the value in the option if the option is `Some` and to `default_value` if it is `None`, effectively converting `Option<bool>` to a `bool`, which we need for the `if`.